# how to fix the side layout in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to fixed the side `nav` when i scroll down [here](http://www.bootply.com/88026)

```
<div class="page-container">  
<!-- top navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>              
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- main area -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div id="scroller" style="background-color: gray; height: 800px">

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `position:fixed` to `.nav` will make as your expected.

```
.nav{
   position:fixed;
}
```

**[Working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6Ze78lsciz)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.main-area {
float:right;
}
#sidebar {
position:fixed;
top: 80px;
left: 0;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/ikpeHyvGZM

Comment: when screen width less 768px, can see the side panel